# Intuition behind optimizing multi-variable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, intuition

The time-independent curve of a projectile motion given an initial angle of launch $\theta$, initial velocity $u$ is given as:

$$ y(\theta,x,u) = x \tan \theta - \frac{g}{2}\frac{x^2}{u^2 } (1 + \tan^2 \theta)$$

Where $y$ is the vertical position, $x$ is the horizontal position and $g$ is the gravitational constant.

If I were to partial differentiate $y$ with respect to $\theta$ and set the derivative equal to zero then I'd arrive at an implicit relation between $\theta, x $ and $u$:

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{u^2}{gx}$$

If I plug this into $y(\theta,x,u)$ then the function reduces two a double variable function $y(x,u)$ but I can't seem to get the interpetation of it. Can someone explain this result in an intuitive way with reasoning as to why that interpretation is correct?

Comment: What is the physical meaning of "partial differentiate y with respect to θ and set the derivative equal to zero"? And why do you ask for "physical meaning" at a mathematics site?

Comment: Interpretation is what I was trying to say.

Comment: Setting the derivative equal to zero gives condition for optimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}=0\;$ you are writing an expression for the critical points of $y$ for a given pair of $(x,u).$ Solving this equation for $\theta$ will yield all values at which $y$ might achieve an extremum (maximum or minimum) when we only change $\theta.$ If you can show that a particular solution $\theta$ is an extreme value, then if you plug it back in to the original equation you will achieve a condition for which $y$ is optimized with respect to the $\theta$ coordinate for any $x$ and $u$.

For example if you want to find the maximum height you can achieve for a given $x$ value and initial velocity $u$ then you would choose (and plug in) $\theta$ that maximizes $y.$